# How can i get input field value using while loop through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using php while loop and want to get value for ajax. my code is

```
while{
<form class="commentform">
  <input type="hidden" class="proid" name="proid[]" value="<?=$rr['id']?>">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control wac" name="comval[]" placeholder="Write a comment..">
  </form>  
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.commentform').on('submit', function(e){
        var comment = $(this).next('.proid').attr('value');
        $('#res').html(comment);
        alert(comment);
        return false;
<script>
```

please guide to get value in while loop for ajax on form submit. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is for `while` case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) as `input` is a child not a sibling. Additionally use [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the current value

```
var comment = $(this).find('.proid').val();
```

instead of

```
var comment = $(this).next('.proid').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also serialize all the inputs of the current form and run through each one like this :

```
$('.commentform').on('submit', function(e){
    var formInputs = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
    jQuery.each(formInputs, function(i, field){
        console.log(field.name + " : " + field.value);
    });
});
```